# Crash on ArrayAdapter creation due to Retrofit enqueue() method incompletion

Tags: android

I have and issue with my Android sample application. Here are two variants of Activity class code and one of them crashes and another one does not and I don't understand why. In the following case the program works fine:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;

@BindView(R.id.lvMain)
ListView lvMain;

@BindView(R.id.tvWelcome)
TextView tvWelcome;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    ((RetrofitlearningApp) getApplication()).getGlobalConfigComponent().inject(this);

    tvWelcome.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    HeroesApi heroesApi = retrofit.create(HeroesApi.class);
    Call<List<Hero>> call = heroesApi.getAll();
    call.enqueue(new HeroesCallback());
}

private List<String> getHeroNames(List<Hero> heroes) {
    return heroes.stream()
            .map(Hero::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private class HeroesCallback implements Callback<List<Hero>> {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Hero>> call, Response<List<Hero>> response) {
        if (!(response.body() == null || response.body().isEmpty())) {
            List<Hero> heroes = response.body();

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getHeroNames(heroes));
            lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            tvWelcome.setText("No heroes found");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No heroes found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Hero>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tvWelcome.setText("No access to Valhalla");
    }
}
```

}

But in this one, although enqueue() method is called and response.body() contains a list, onResponse() seems to be never called, and the field "heroes" remains null and the program crashes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;

@BindView(R.id.lvMain)
ListView lvMain;

@BindView(R.id.tvWelcome)
TextView tvWelcome;

private List<Hero> heroes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    ((RetrofitlearningApp) getApplication()).getGlobalConfigComponent().inject(this);

    tvWelcome.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    HeroesApi heroesApi = retrofit.create(HeroesApi.class);
    Call<List<Hero>> call = heroesApi.getAll();
    call.enqueue(new HeroesCallback());

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getHeroNames(heroes));
    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private List<String> getHeroNames(List<Hero> heroes) {
    return heroes.stream()
            .map(Hero::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private class HeroesCallback implements Callback<List<Hero>> {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Hero>> call, Response<List<Hero>> response) {
        if (!(response.body() == null || response.body().isEmpty())) {
            heroes = response.body();
        } else {
            tvWelcome.setText("No heroes found");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No heroes found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Hero>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tvWelcome.setText("No access to Valhalla");
    }
}
```

}

Would you, please, explain me  this phenomenon?

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback is called asynchronously. It isn't executed when you call `enqueue()`, instead it's called at some point in time after that when an answer from server arrives.

You're trying to access `heroes` right after your `enqueue()` and of course get an NPE.

To address this you should access your `heroes` variable only when you got the response. As an option move

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getHeroNames(heroes));
lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
```

to your callback.